# \parbox and horizontal rule inside a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm building a table and I wish to have the contents of one of my cells break a line in order to keep the table nice and tight and keep it on the page (not to mention avoid excess whitespace). So I'm using a `\parbox`.

However, because the content of some of the cells is in Hindi and the vowel diacritics tend to clash with horizontal rules (or at least everything has a very cramped appearance) I've decided to stretch the table out a bit by using

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
```

However, this of course means that there is far far too little vertical space (none, in fact) between the contents of the `\parbox` and the rule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \parbox{57pt}{\textsc{Inf}/\textsc{Ger}/\\ Obligatory} & Conjunctive
  \\ \hline
  Lorem & Ipsum
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly what I need is to specify a height of the `\parbox`, or add a strut. The problem is, I don't know what the normal vertical separation is! What I would like is precisely the normal amount of vertical space between content and rule but obviously that's taking into account the new value of `\arraystretch`.

Comment: is there some reason why you not use `p{...}` column type for the first column and have multi lines cell (in the first column) without `\parbox`?

Comment: @Zarko Hmmmmmmmmmm no, actually, it works very well with `p{...}` the only tiny annoyance is an Underfull \hbox warning that I can't seem to avoid

Comment: i don't receive any warnings, nor bad boxes (for your example).

Comment: @Zarko that's interesting, if I use `\begin{tabular}{p{57pt}c}
  \textsc{Inf}/\textsc{Ger}\slash{}Obligatory & Conjunctive \\ \hline
  Lorem & Ipsum
\end{tabular}` I definitely get `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--8`

Comment: However the result is perfect =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if one of the following solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{57pt}c}
\textsc{Inf/Ger}/\newline Obligatory & Conjunctive  \\ \midrule
Lorem                                & Ipsum
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{p{57pt}c}
\textsc{Inf/Ger}/\newline Obligatory & Conjunctive  \\ \hline
Lorem                                & Ipsum
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Changing the value of \arraystretch has a drawback: the contents of the cells look no more vertically centred in the cells. You can prevent large contents from touching horizontal rules above and below with the `cellspace` package, which lets you define  *minimal* vertical spacing between the contents and the above and below cells in columns with specifiers prefixed with the letter `S`.

Concerning the underfull `\hbox` message in `p` columns, this is probably a problem with hyphenation with comparatively short lines. This situation can be greatly improved loading `ragged2e` and using `>{\RaggedRight}p{some length}` in the table preamble.

In the following code, I prefered to load `makecell`, which allows for line breaking in standard cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ScSc}
\makecell{\textsc{Inf}/\textsc{Ger}/\\ Obligatory} & Conjunctive
  \\ \hline
  Lorem & Ipsum
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really useful package +1! At first I felt a bit silly for asking the question (*of course* I could use a `p` column specifier!), but now I'm really glad I asked it!